# Error: Dom.php problem during magento template install

Tags: php, xml, magento2

i've been trying to install a new template to a fresh magento instance but as soon as I deploy the new template I receive on the front end:

"There has been an error processing your request"

This is even before enabling the template so something in the install package is causing an issue. Back end works fine except for Content > Pages which displays.

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /home/sitename/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 451
```

The report gives the following:

```
{"0":"Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in \/home\/sitename\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Config\/Dom.php on line 451","1":"<pre>#1 DOMDocument->loadXML('') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Config\/Dom.php:451]\
n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Config\\Dom->_initDom('') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Config\/Dom.php:148]\
n#3 Magento\\Framework\\Config\\Dom->merge('') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Config\/Reader\/Filesystem.php:153]\
n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Config\\Reader\\Filesystem->_readFiles(&Magento\\Framework\\Config\\FileIterator#000000003e734d8c00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Config\/Reader\/Filesystem.php:132]\
n#5 Magento\\Framework\\Config\\Reader\\Filesystem->read('frontend') called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Route\/Config\/Reader\/Proxy.php:95]\
n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Route\\Config\\Reader\\Proxy->read('frontend') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Route\/Config.php:92]\
n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Route\\Config->_getRoutes('frontend') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Route\/Config.php:136]\
n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Route\\Config->getModulesByFrontName('cms') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:280]\
n#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->matchAction(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#, array('moduleFrontName' => 'cms', 'actionPath' => NULL, 'actionName' => NULL)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Router\/Base.php:167]\
n#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Router\\Base->match(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:95]\
n#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\
n#12 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\
n#13 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\
n#14 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#000000003e73484900000000059727da#, &Closure#000000003e734f2900000000059727da#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\
n#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]\
n#16 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#000000003e73484900000000059727da#, &Closure#000000003e734f2900000000059727da#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\
n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\
n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\
n#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000003e734b3e00000000059727da#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:137]\
n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\
n#21 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\
n#22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000003e734a2d00000000059727da#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Not sure how to interpret this exactly. Does anyone have any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Solved

Two files failed to upload correctly leaving a 0kb file

contact_index_index.xml

routes.xml